# Почему так в Python?

Tags: python

Не пойму...

```
>>> 5 * 32 / 9
>>> 17
```

Но тут же:

```
>>> 5 * -32 / 9 
>>> -18
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
5 * 32 / 9 = 17.7777...
```

Округляется к меньшему числу, тоесть к 17

```
5 * -32 / 9 = -17.7777...
```

Меньшее число -18

Comment: Благодарю. Попробовал интерпритатор Ruby - работает так же.